# Troubleshooting system.io.fileloadexception

Tags: .net

I have a .net 3.5 WinForms application that runs fine on my machine, but on another machine it immediately crashes with a system.io.fileloadexception. Unfortunately, there are absolutely no details on which file failed to load, so I do not know where the problem actually is.

I believe I know which one it could be (SQL Server Compact edition), but before I aimlessly hunt, I wonder if there is a proper way to find out what caused the fileloadexception, other than using FileMon from SysInternals.

The only error message is:

> EventType clr20r3, P1 myapplication.exe, P2 2.1.0.0, P3 490eca78, P4 myapplication, P5 2.1.0.0, P6 490eca78, P7 2e, P8 21, P9 system.io.fileloadexception, P10 NIL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turn on [fusion logging](http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx)?

[This blog entry](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2007/12/we-were-crashin.html) from Brad Wilson gives information on what to do if that fails...

Comment: I completely missed that fusion logger. It solved my problem within a few minutes because the logs are really useful. The FUSLOGVW.exe can just be copied to a machine (no .net SDK needed) and it's possible to set the logging settings through it. Magic. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I was getting the same exception as Michael, the logger helped me solve the problem in minutes!

Answer (score 6):

You could try making your `Main()` method more robust to catch (and display) the exception... [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295161/).

Frequently, the problem is that too much code gets into the outermost `Main()` method. JIT has to be able to fully understand `Main()`, otherwise **none** of your code can run. By making `Main()` simpler, you stand a chance. In the linked example, if `MainCore()` fails: fine, we can still catch the exception in `Main()`.

This works because JIT is done on a method-by-method basis... i.e. `MainCore()` is not JITted until it is invoked, by which time we already have our try/catch in place.

Answer (score 2):

Hook and log [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Grab the Microsoft Debugging Tools SDK, and use either windbg or cordbg to attach and run your application. This should give you at least a clue where the problem is, if not pinpoint the problem.